# Identify the discrepancy between two headers(color the false value)

Tags: python, pandas, colors, header

I'm using below queries to identify the discrepancy between two headers and its working good but I need to color the false value in df1.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('E:\\New folder\\New folder\\AOQ_Factual.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col=0)

df2 = pd.read_excel('E:\\New folder\\New folder\\Input_header.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col=1)

template_check = df.columns.values == df1.columns.values
```

Result:

```
array([False,  True,  False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: what do you mean by "color" ? color where?

Comment: Need to fill yellow color, which df1 header is not matched with df2 header.

Comment: you are trying to read an excel file using pandas and then changing the color in the original excel file?

Comment: if that is indeed what you are trying to do, try using [this guide](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/) or look into [openpyxl module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: I will explain elaborately.  I have two excel(Book 1, Book 2). Both books are having following headers. Book 1 [Name], [address], [City], [state], [Pin code], [Phone].   Book 2 [Company name], [address], [City], [state], [Pin code], [Phone].   I want to compare both headers if any book 1 header is not matched with book 2 then the different header should be mark with yellow color in book 1.     Hope it will clear.

Comment: yes, its more clear now, update this information in your question and look at the links i gave you, tell us if you get stuck and show where you get stuck